# Need hamburger mobile menu icon instead of text

Tags: html, css, mobile, icons

[image]

Hi all,
I want to set hamburger icon instead of text.I am able to set background image but text does't appear.Following is my code

```css
  #mobileMenuLink ul li { background:url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5adfd10929711421a9b29d21/t/5ae49f061ae6cfa83d2ba0ad/1524933475120/images.png?format=100w')    no-repeat; }
     }
```

Comment: I'm not too clear on what your question is, but for that icon you can either use the ☰ Unicode character or do it with CSS - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_icon.asp

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 6px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>A menu icon:</p>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this code..but problem was that menu text doesn't disappears.so i used trick..i added new <a></a> link with jquery then make this as first child and orginal as 2nd child..and hide the 2nd menu text link.and now  hamburger mobile menu icons works fine.